# What is our 404 Image supposed to be of?

Tags: support, design

So, I saw a [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/262279/is-changing-the-page-not-found-title-to-something-dedicates-to-its-site-a-good) over on Meta.SE about the 404 page images and how they all relate to the subject of the site to some degree. It made me wonder, what's our 404 image...

[image: Movies & TV 404 image]

It's all Egyptian to me... or some other made-up language.

Can anyone give some context for this image?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

They're the hieroglyphs from the countdown timer on *Lost*.

[image]

You can read more about them [here](http://lostpedia.wikia.com/wiki/Hieroglyphs) (specifically, these are our 404 page symbols because in *Lost*, they basically mean [system failure](http://lostpedia.wikia.com/wiki/System_Failure)).

Comment: Was this voted on? That's pretty cryptic too.

Comment: @cde I don't think so, they were just made by the design team. But anyway, the [error](http://movies.stackexchange.com/error) and [captcha](http://movies.stackexchange.com/captcha) pages are much better anyway.

Comment: @TomCody never noticed them